# Select using in statement from multiple tables and display everything regardless the result

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables.

The first table "projects" is like this:

```
id  |   title
28  |   pr28
31  |   pr31
65  |   pr65
74  |   pr74
```

The second table "stages" is like this:

```
pr_id   |   id  |   t_id|   title   |   comments
28      |   65  |   1   |   st1     |   bla
28      |   86  |   3   |   st3     |   blaaaa
31      |   132 |   1   |   st1     |   blabla
65      |   189 |   1   |   st1     |   bli
65      |   190 |   2   |   st2     |   blibli
65      |   224 |   3   |   st3     |   bliblib
74      |   319 |   3   |   st3     |   blibli
74      |   333 |   5   |   st5     |   blibli
```

The third table "stad_ids" is like this:

```
id  |   title
1   |   st1
2   |   st2
3   |   st3
4   |   st4
5   |   st5
```

I want to find the projects from the first table, which have t_ids 1 or 2. No problem here:

```
 SELECT a.id, st.t_id, st.title, st.comments
 FROM  `stages` AS st
 JOIN `projects` AS a ON a.id = st.pr_id
 and a.id IN (SELECT a.id FROM stages as st
 JOIN `projects` AS a ON a.id = st.pr_id
 AND st.t_id in (1,2))
 order by a.id
```

This outputs:

```
id  |   t_id    |   title   |   comments
28  |   1       |   st1     |   bla
31  |   1       |   st1     |   blabla
65  |   1       |   st1     |   bli
65  |   2       |   st2     |   blibli
```

Now, I want to display the stages which have ids 2 or 3 from the projects, which have t_id 1 or 2.

```
SELECT a.id, st.t_id, st.title, st.comments FROM  `stages` AS st JOIN
`projects` AS a ON a.id = st.pr_id and st.t_id in (2,3) and a.id IN
(SELECT a.id FROM stages as st JOIN `projects` AS a ON a.id = st.pr_id
AND st.t_id in (1,2))
order by a.id
```

This outputs:

```
id  |   t_id    |   title   |   comments
28  |   3       |   st3     |   blaaaa
65  |   2       |   st2     |   blibli
65  |   3       |   st3     |   bliblib
```

Instead I want to have the output below:

```
id  |   t_id    |   title   |   comments
28  |   2       |   st2     |   "NO VALUE"
28  |   3       |   st3     |   blaaaa
65  |   2       |   st2     |   blibli
65  |   3       |   st3     |   bliblib
```

I've tried to use the third table:

```
SELECT distinct a.id, ids.id AS t_id, ids.title, st.comments
FROM  `stages` AS st
JOIN `stad_ids` AS ids ON ids.id in (2,3)
JOIN `projects` AS a ON a.id = st.pr_id
and st.t_id in (2,3)
and a.id IN (SELECT a.id FROM stages as st
JOIN `projects` AS a ON a.id = st.pr_id
AND st.t_id in (1,2)) 
order by a.id
```

but the output repeats the comments.

```
id  |   t_id    |   title   |   comments
28  |   2       |   st2     |   blaaaa
28  |   3       |   st3     |   blaaaa
65  |   2       |   st2     |   blibli
65  |   3       |   st3     |   bliblib
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add relevant data based on your query, Where can I see **2 or 3 from the projects** ?

Comment: Please add proper column name as per sample you provided in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the target projects and do a cross join with 2 rows of stage ids (2 and 3) to create every possible combinations  of project id, stage id/title.  Use a left join to bring in the comments.

```
SELECT a.id, ids.id as t_id, ids.title, COALESCE(st.comments, '"NO VALUE"') as comments
FROM `stad_ids` as ids
CROSS JOIN `projects` as a
LEFT JOIN `stages` as st ON ids.id = st.t_id and a.id = st.pr_id
WHERE ids.id in (2, 3) AND
      a.id IN
    (SELECT a.id FROM stages as st JOIN `projects` AS a ON a.id = st.pr_id
         AND st.t_id in (1,2)) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `stages` as st1 WHERE st1.pr_id = a.id AND st1.t_id in (2, 3))
ORDER BY a.id,  ids.id;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21a687/50)